# Golang HTTP and file caching

Tags: http, go, http-live-streaming

I have an application, written in Go, which runs an HTTP server and uses  `http.ServeFile()` to serve a file which is being updated 3 times per second; this is an audio streaming index file for a HTTP Live Stream which I need to operate in near zero latency, hence the frequent updates.  I can see from the logging in my Go server application that this file really is being updated 3 times per second and I call `Sync()` on the file each time it is updated to make sure that it is written to disk.

My problem is that, on the browser side (Chrome), while this file is being requested several times per second, it is only actually being served once a second; on all the other occasions the server is returning 304, indicating that the file is unchanged:

[image]

What might be causing this behaviour and how could I make the file be served on each request?

Comment: Modification time checking in HTTP only has resolution to the second.

Comment: Out of curiousity, if this is being written and served by the same process, why serve the file at all? Why not just write a handler to serve the current data directly from memory?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. I could indeed serve the data from memory, just easier to use ServeFile() and be able to cat the file when I need to but you're quite right, I will modify my code to serve the file from memory. I guess I could probably even read it from disk first...

Comment: You can still write it to disk when it's updated if you want a copy on disk, but the file seems like an unnecessarily roundabout way to serve that data.

Comment: To answer the original question, http.ServeFile does not send Cache-Control: max-age=0, which would prevent caching. In absence of Cache-Control, browsers apply heuristics based on Last-Modified to compute cache validity. Also, Sync helps against data loss after a power outage or system crash. It is not required to read up-to-date data. In fact, it hurts performance.

Answer (score 0):

As state in the comments, it turns out that the modification time checking in HTTP has a minimum resolution of 1 second and so, where a file needs to be change and server more frequently than that, it's best to serve it oneself from RAM.  For instance, store it in a slice called `content` and serve that slice with something like:

`http.ServeContent(w, r, filepath.Base(r.URL.Path), time.Time{}, bytes.NewReader(content))`

Answer (score 0):

Modification time checking in HTTP only has resolution to the second. However, the alternative is to use entity-tags ('etags'), which can be updated as often as the server needs to change the content.

Therefore your use-case would work better via etags instead of modification times. An etag contains an opaque string that either does or doesn't match.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3,

> An entity-tag is an opaque validator for
> differentiating between multiple representations of the same
> resource, regardless of whether those multiple representations are
> due to resource state changes over time, content negotiation
> resulting in multiple representations being valid at the same time,
> or both.

Detection of change by the client is usually done using the if-none-match header (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.2)

> If-None-Match is primarily used in conditional GET requests to enable
> efficient updates of cached information with a minimum amount of
> transaction overhead.